# How do you reset the master key in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Our old DB admin is gone, any ideas?

It looks it was set up many years ago.

Comment: Did the DB admin leave any documentation behind?

Comment: Are you referring to the server master key or the database master key? Why are you trying to reset it?

Comment: no documentation, trying to reset it as we are setting up a mirror server now our db admin is trying to copy over the existing db.

Comment: Find your old questions and which ever answer is correct, check the check mark next to that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to reset the database master key you just need to use the ALTER MASTER KEY statement adding in the keyword FORCE.

```
ALTER MASTER KEY 
FORCE REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourNewPassword!';
```

Comment: are you able to encrypt specific tables? such as just credit card data for PCI Compliance purposes?

Comment: Sure, but not by just setting the database master key.  That requires changing the code which is storing and reading the data so that it is encrypted and decrypted as needed.  That's a much bigger job.

Comment: Does this affect only the active DB or more DBs than that? I want to use the `FORCE` option, which seems to cause data loss, but only for one of the DBs for which I cannot figure out the master key password.